# Flutter Web: HtmlElementView and TextArea

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, codemirror

I wanted to embed a `TextArea` in `Flutter Web` page so that I can use `CodeMirror` in a `Flutter Web` page. `CodeMirror` expects a `TextArea`. I tried to add `CodeMirror` as follows

```
class _CodeEditorState extends State<CodeEditor> {
  late TextAreaElement element;
  late CodeMirror editor;
  @override
  void initState() {

// ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory('#textContainer', (int viewId) {
      element = TextAreaElement()..id = '#textContainer';
      return element;
    });

    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      var options = {
        'theme': 'zenburn',
        'continueComments': {'continueLineComment': false},
        'autoCloseTags': true,
        'mode': 'dart',
        'extraKeys': {
          'Ctrl-Space': 'autocomplete',
          'Cmd-/': 'toggleComment',
          'Ctrl-/': 'toggleComment'
        }
      };
      editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(element, options: options);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Code Editor'),
      ),
      body: Flex(
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            flex: 2,
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 640,
              height: 360,
              child: HtmlElementView(viewType: '#textContainer'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _divider() {
    return const Flexible(
      flex: 0,
      fit: FlexFit.tight,
      child: VerticalDivider(thickness: 1, width: 1),
    );
  }
}
```

But it appears as below. How can I make it work inside the `Flutter`'s UI ? Is there a better way to embed `CodeMirror` in `Flutter Web` ?
[image]